# Alerts in Azure monitor/analytics

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks

I have 6 different application insights I would like to create alert for. But when I go to alerts I can only select one resource. How do you monitor a specific set of services?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you should create all the 6 Application Insights in a same Resource Group, or move those 6 existing Application insights in a same Resource Group.

Then during create alert rule, select the resource group, then all these 6 application insights will be selected. The screenshot as below:

[image]